# Django - Issue with wrong query string in model filter

Tags: python, django, django-models

I need to run query in my view.py

My current code is as follows :

```
q = Owner.objects.filter(name__contains='Maximus')
```

this code is working fine.

I have to prepare query string name__contains='Maximus' based on multiple columns values. For that I am preparing a queryString but this is throwing error.

```
queryString = ""
queryString += "name__contains="+"'"+ownerName+"'"
```

This query string when I put in filter

```
q = Owner.objects.filter(queryString)
```

[and in debug its value is like 'name__contains=\'Maximus\'']

this is not working. Please suggest how to resolve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build a dictionary with the arguments for the query, in the following way:

```
kwargs = {'name__contains': owner_name, 'field': value, ... }
```

then you can pass the dictionary with the arguments like this

```
q = Owner.objects.filter(**kwargs)
```